# prevent a div content go over other div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have built an html layout with css and divs. I have divs called top (which is the header), left (where the links are for the page) and center (for the displaying images).

When I click on a link to display images on left, I might get images that are bigger than the browser window, where I need to scroll. I can scrool but images goes over the top section where my header is not seen. what I would like to do is, top section always on the browser window. When I scroll the images in center, if they go above the my top div, I like to hide sections that are crossing the top div. Is there a way to do this in css?

```
#top {
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}

#left {


    padding:0;
    border: 0;
    width: 350px;
    overflow: scroll;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px; 
    bottom:0px;
    min-height:950px;

}

#center1 {
margin-left:352px;
padding:0;
border: 0;
float: left;
position:static;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the position of `#center1` to static?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `z-index` attribute on your header and set it to 100 or 1000. Z-index only works if you are using `position:relative`, `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`.

```
#top {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: @Rouge Coder, what about center? it did not work. Still seeing the same behavior. I have all three divs as position.fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a persistent Header. I hope this works for you, although you will have to modify it to fit your need...

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Constant Header</title>
<style type="text/css">

body 
{ 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}

#header_container 
{ 
background:#eee; 
border:1px solid #666; 
height:60px; 
left:0; 
position:fixed; 
width:100%; 
top:0; 
}
#header
{ 
line-height:60px; 
margin:0 auto; 
width:940px; 
text-align:center; 
}

/* CSS for the content of page. Top padding of 80px to make sure the header do not         overlap the content.*/

#container 
{ 
margin:0 auto;
overflow:auto;
padding:80px 0;
width:100%;
}
#content{}

#left {
padding:0;
border: 0;
width: 150px;
float: left;
position: fixed;
top: 85px; 
bottom:0px;
min-height:950px;
}

#center1 {
margin-left:152px;
padding:0;
border: 0;
float: left;
position:static;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_container">
  <div id="header">
      Header Content
  </div>
</div>
<!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
     <a href="large_img.jpg" alt="large image">nav to img </a>
  </div>
  <div id="center1">
    <img id="imgLogo" src="" alt="large image"/>
      ...
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Page Content -->
</body>
</html>
```